# How to convert UnixDate to mysql_format or php

Tags: php, mysql

I am connecting to an API and its returning the date in UnixDate, not unix timestamp. How do I convert this format to be able to save it in a datetime field?

Example: 'Mon Jun 09 21:59:59 UTC 2025'

Comment: I added some references and links to documentation so that you can verify my claims.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Mon Jun 09 21:59:59 UTC 2025'));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) command will turn a UNIX timestamp into a multitude of different formats. So, abstractly, if you do the following:

```
date(*formatCodeString*, *timeStampInt*);
```

You should be able to get the format that you need.

### Step 1: Determine Format Code for MySQL DATETIME

The MySQL 5.7 Manual States.

> The **DATETIME** type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in **'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS'** format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Thus we need to create a format code string that represents the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

From the PHP manual for `date()`.

YYYY = Y

MM = m

DD = d

HH = H

MM = i

SS = s

PHP `date()` format string for MySQL `DATETIME` =

`'Y-m-d H:i:s'`

### Step 2: Convert a date string to UNIX timestamp.

Use the PHP function [stringtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). The PHP manual states that this:

> ... parse[s] about any English textual datetime description into a
>   Unix timestamp.

UNIX timestamp =

`strtotime('Mon Jun 09 21:59:59 UTC 2025');`

### Step 3: Use PHP date format code and UNIX timestamp with `date()`

MySQL `DATETIME` string =

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Mon Jun 09 21:59:59 UTC 2025'));`

That should do it. Good luck!